# Facebook pulls Plesk default page in web scrape

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dns, plesk, server

I set up a client's website (wordpress) I run my servers with Plesk with 1and1 dedicated.  The site works perfectly, we are able to go to individual webpages, follow links and there are no issues.  The issues arise when using Facebook or Google analytics. When we try to share the link in Facebook it pulls the default Parallels page and images.

We have used the Facebook dev debug tools and it nothing has changed, the OG errors are as follows:

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.  

Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.  

Inferred Property   The 'og:description'
property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. 

Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property
should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. og:image could not be downloaded or is too small    og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image
that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image 'http://www.4you2take.com/img/apps/pdfwl-box.gif' will be used
instead.
```

Since then I have scraped all my sites using the Facebook debug tool that reside on the same server and have their DNS hosted by 1and1.  They all result in the same parallels default page and error above.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a solution?

One of the sites in question is http://www.4you2take.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did already have the specified Meta Tags with the necessary open graph properties.

Turns out that the DNS was not pulling in properly.  Not sure if the server was configured properly or not.  What I ended up doing is taking the DNS management away from the server and putting it back to the registrar.

This did the trick and it no longer pointed to phantom Plesk information landing pages.

Answer (score 3):

After several hours of trying to debug this issue and playing with DNS settings/servers, I have a solution that works for me.

I noticed that requests from Facebook were coming from an IPv6 server, but the Apache configuration files generated by Plesk did not include IPv6 addresses in the VirualHost declarations.

To debug, I changed the following line in my Apache .conf file:

`<VirtualHost IPv4:80>`

to:

`<VirtualHost IPv4:80 [IPv6]:80>`

...and immediately upon restarting Apache, Facebook was able to successfully scrape my site.

**The is not a permanent solution because Plesk will rewrite the configuration files, so you have to go into the Plesk panel and make sure that your server's IPv6 address is assigned to the Subscription that owns the domain in question.** In my case, only the IPv4 was assigned to the subscription.

The setting can be found under "Change Hosting Settings" for each particular Subscription.

Andrew-- I am new to this site and can not yet reply to you directly, but I wanted to point out that the DNS solution you proposed does not work. In fact, scraping the site you mentioned with Facebook still produces content from a default Plesk page:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://www.4you2take.com

Hopefully the solution I've proposed here will be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

This error message "property should be explicitly provided" is quite clear

You should define this properties in code of your site in `<head>` like:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.4you2take.com/" />
<meta property="og:title" content="4 you 2 take.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Your portal for Freecycling listings around the world. List for free and get for free. 4 You 2 Take is where everything is for free!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.4you2take.com/some-your-image.jpg" />
```

This guide describers this properties https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags